# I'm trying to install bpy but I keep getting "LookupError: unknown encoding: future_fstrings"

Tags: python, blender, bpy

```
 Using cached bpy-0.0.0a0.tar.gz (19 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\kwale cedric\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tokenize.py", line 344, in find_cookie
          codec = lookup(encoding)
      LookupError: unknown encoding: future_fstrings

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 28, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\kwale cedric\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tokenize.py", line 396, in open
          encoding, lines = detect_encoding(buffer.readline)
        File "C:\Users\kwale cedric\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tokenize.py", line 383, in detect_encoding
          encoding = find_cookie(second)
        File "C:\Users\kwale cedric\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tokenize.py", line 352, in find_cookie
          raise SyntaxError(msg)
      SyntaxError: unknown encoding for 'C:\\Users\\kwale cedric\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dc132n33\\bpy_e9289df316154351a1730ff323d0ba6b\\setup.py': future_fstrings
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

The PyPi page of bpy seems to contain instructions, regarding the "fstrings":

`py -3.7-64 -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel future-fstrings`

Found on:

https://pypi.org/project/bpy/